# Phonegap - I cant get the phonegap file API work to save my captured image to a custom directory in the file system

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have been developing a phonegap app. I am using the Phonegap file API to save my captured picture to a custom directory. But it saved to a temporary path like 'cdvfile://localhost/...'. When I access the image usin the URL, it is not working

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURL, function(fileEntry) {
   App.fileSystemRoot.getDirectory("attachmentsFolder", {create : true}, function(dataDir) {
                        alert("dir= "+dataDir.toURL()); // return 'cdvfile://' path
                        // move the file
                        fileEntry.moveTo(dataDir, fileName+fileExtension, function(newFileEntry) {
                                alert("file= "+newFileEntry.toURL()); // returns 'cdvfile' temporary path here also

                    }, function(){});
                }, function(){});
```

Please help me to resove this issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using this phonegap plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: Did you understand my issue? My problem is not with camera API. I got the picture from the camera successfully but cant save to a folder.

Comment: Yes I know the camera API will work. I want to save the captured picture to a persistent folder in the device. You cant do that just with Camera API but only with File API.